# CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 241

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I am working with core bluetooth. I am doing simple write operation . And at peripheral side getting that value into the :

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
```

BUt as I implemented above method the it is taking too much time to write the value . And I am getting the warning at central side :

```
 CoreBluetooth[WARNING] Unknown error: 241
```

This is quite strange because when I looked towards the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011288) I found that the error codes are only from 0 to 17 . Does any one have solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

`241` or `0xF1` is in the "Application Error" range of the Bluetooth Attribute Protocol (ATT), see Volume 3, Part F, 3.4.1 Error Handling of the Bluetooth 4.0 specification. Unfortunately, Apple did not document the use of these.

My experience also has been that iOS automatically responds with an ATT error response with `0xF1` on behalf of the application, in case it does not call `-[peripheralManager respondToRequest:withResult:]` in time, in response to the `-peripheralManager:didReceiveReadRequest:` delegate callback.

Answer (score 1):

I have still not cleared with that error code . But now solved that problem . I have created characteristic with property `CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse` so above error is removed . Also data writing smoothly to the peripheral . But still  wanted to know that error .

Comment: What was writing your characteristic value? Was it writing with a response request ?

Comment: @Larme: Initially it was the response request and now I have changed it to without response.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling:

Swift:

```
func respondToRequest(request: CBATTRequest!, withResult result: CBATTError)
```

Objective-C:

```
- (void)respondToRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request withResult:(CBATTError)result
```

And on success pass CBATTError.Success and call the function only once. E.G. from the delegate callback:

```
func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: AnyObject[]!)
```

Call:

```
peripheral.respondToRequest(requests[0] as CBATTRequest, withResult: CBATTError.Success)
```

This resolved the issue for us.

Comment: Where should I call respondToRequest method  ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Michael. I ever met the same problem before and finally got resolved.

If a central device writes data to peripheral devices, it may work on either *CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithoutResponse* mode or *CBCharacteristicPropertyWriteWithResponse* mode. The first one does not require the peripheral to respond but the second one does. If the central device did not receive response from peripheral while requires, this error will happen. Since the central device only waits for a few seconds, you should call the method

```
- (void)respondToRequest:(CBATTRequest *)request withResult:(CBATTError)result
```

to respond the writing operation as long as the delegate method

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didReceiveWriteRequests:(NSArray *)requests
```

is called.

If the writing data is large, peripheral may receive more than one CBATTRequest. Remember only respond to the first request of the requests array.